# vuex having " Error in mounted hook: 'InternalError: too much recursion' " What's interesting I'm not calling any recursive functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Here is my mounted hook in Index.vue and there is no any other methods

```
     mounted(){
        for(let ref in this.$refs)
        {
          let ele = this.$refs[ref].$el; // storing DOM element into let
          let offset = ele.offsetTop; //storing offset from a top of this DOM into let
    
          this.$store.dispatch('scroll/set_vals', { ref, ele, offset }) // calling action in the store and passing those variables
        }
  }
```

And here is a module `scroll` is mainly declaring variables and storing into them payload. As for me everything looks nice and clean, but I'm having error in console saying "[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "Internal Error: too much recursion"". And I don't even know where to start cause as you can see there is no recursion called. And know I actually find out which line of code giving me error. I commented out below

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    currentBlock: 'intro',
    blocks: {
      greet: {
        el: null,
        active: true,
        offset: 0
      },
      interests: {
        el: null,
        active: false,
        offset: 0
      },
      projects: {
        el: null,
        active: false,
        offset: 0
      },
      contact: {
        el: null,
        active: false,
        offset: 0
      }
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    set_offset(state, payload){
      state.blocks[payload.ref].offset = payload.offset;
    },
    set_ele(state, payload){
      state.blocks[payload.ref].el = payload.ele; // This line is where I have ERROR!! I consoled logged and payload.ele has DOM element and nothing else. But if I comment error disappears 
    },
  },
  actions:{
    set_vals({commit}, payload){
      let ref = payload.ref;
      let ele = payload.ele;
      let offset = payload.offset;

      commit('set_offset', { ref, offset})
      commit('set_ele', { ref, ele })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out the dispatch in mounted?

Comment: it works fine, no error. I think error is. It works fine if I comment  set_ele(state, payload) functrion in dispatch, so Im assuming error is there. Error is when I assign DOM element to variable

Comment: I tried like that still nothing state.blocks[payload.ref]['el'] = payload.ele;